# How to make linq query for grouped list based on a join condition of two table more efficient

Tags: c#, visual-studio, linq, entity-framework-core, ef-core-6.0

I'm working with Entity Framework Core. I'm trying to write a linq query which takes inputs from two tables `SccmTable` and `Sailpoint` table.

I want to satisfy these 3 conditions:

1. `lcstate = deleted` in `sailpoint` table
2. `UserName` in `sailpoint` equals `Username` in `sccm` table
3. Select only rows with unique machine name

I tried this method

```
var result = (from r in DBContext.SccmTable
              join s in DBContext.Sailpoint on r.UserName equals s.Username
              where s.LcState == "DELETED"
              select r).ToList() 
                       .GroupBy(r => r.MachineName)
                       .Select(g => g.First());
```

And I also tried this code:

```
var result = DBContext.SccmTable
                      .Where(x => DBContext.Sailpoint
                      .Where(y => y.LcState == "DELETED")
                      .Select(y => y.Username)
                      .Contains(x.UserName))
                      .Select(x => x)
                      .Distinct().ToList();
```

These two methods are working, but they are not efficient. I tried other ways as well, they are working but not fast. I don't know how to make it more efficient.

Is there any other way to improve the performance of these queries?

Thank you!

Comment: Are these database tables? How many rows? Are thye indexed? Is the inefficiency in the database or in the C# code?

Comment: Not using linq should give you a ~10% boost. Adding a view for that join should speed things up as well.  Another option would be to use a stored procedure for deletions, that adds deleted records, or reference to them, to a table, which would avoid the join and operational overhead of maintaining the view.

Comment: How many records do you expect in the results?

Comment: #Nick Mc  Yes these are database tables.Number of rows are around 2 million.The inefficiency is in c# code because other linq queries for the same table was faster than this.

Comment: #jwdonahue I'm expecting 2,000 to 5,000 records as result.I'm using linq instead of other ways because this may need to be changed further in other layers.

Comment: Neither of your queries precisely satisfies your stated requirement #3 - "select only records with unique machine name."  Your first query picks one (arbitrary) SccmTable row per machine name, but the machine name may not have been be unique. Your second query selects entire distinct SccmTable rows (possibly all, depending on how equality is defined). I suggest that you rethink what you really want from your query. Do you want just a list of the machine names, or entire SccmTable rows? If multiple with the same machine name, which one do you want to select?  The earliest?  The latest? Any?

Comment: I want to select records with unique machine name,it can be any record if there are multiple records

Comment: Which EF Core version?

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer Version="6.0.9",
    Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools Version="6.0.9"

Comment: Updated answer, tested on EF Core `6.0.23`, I hope nothing changed.

Comment: @Sapris You never answered the most essential question: are the tables indexed properly? These queries really shouldn't be hard at all for any db engine. Look at the query plan and add any missing indexes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most efficient is to use Window Function [ROW_NUMBER](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16), but with EF Core you have to use `FromSql`

```cs
var result = DBContext.SccmTable.FromSql(@"
    SELECT 
        ss.*
    FROM (
            SELECT 
                r.*, 
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY r.MachineName) AS RN
            FROM SccmTable r
            JOIN Sailpoint s ON r.UserName = s.UserName
            WHERE s.LcState = 'DELETED'
        )
    WHERE ss.RN = 1")
    .ToList();
```

Less efficient, but With EF Core 6 and higher, should work this query:

```cs
var result = (from r in DBContext.SccmTable
              join s in DBContext.Sailpoint on r.UserName equals s.Username
              where s.LcState == "DELETED"
              group r by r.MachineName into g
              select g.First())
              .ToList();
```

---

If you don't want to leave LINQ and produce most effective SQL, you can use extension [linq2db.EntityFrameworkCore](https://github.com/linq2db/linq2db.EntityFrameworkCore) (note that I'm one of the creators).

Extension allows using Window Functions in LINQ Query:

```cs
var query = 
    from r in DBContext.SccmTable.ToLinqToDB()
    join s in DBContext.Sailpoint on r.UserName equals s.Username
    where s.LcState == "DELETED"
    select new 
    {
        r,
        RN = Sql.Ext.RowNumbert().Over()
            .PartitionBy(r.MachineName)
            .ToValue()
    } into ss
    where ss.RN == 1
    select ss.r;

var result = query.ToList();
```

Note that it is good to specify how to Order items in `MachineName` group. Many databases do not allow `ROW_NUMBER` without `ORDER BY` part.

Comment: FromSql shows me error , I changed it to FromSqlInterpolated and it works.Thank you.